# Is there a way to type a TypeScript method decorator to restrict the type of the method it can decorate?

Tags: typescript, contravariance, typescript-decorator

I want to write a TypeScript method decorator that can only be applied to methods with a certain type of first argument. It's a common pattern in the codebase I'm working in to pass around a request context that has handles for database, metrics, logging, etc. I'd like to write a decorator that requires one of these resources in the request context, but is otherwise agnostic to the shape of the request context.

Here's a stylized example:

```
interface MyResource {
    logMetricsEtc(...args: any): void;
}

interface HasResourceINeed {
    myResource: MyResource;
}

function myDecorator<TFn extends ((tContext: HasResourceINeed, ...rest: any) => any)>(
    _target: object,
    key: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<TFn>,
): TypedPropertyDescriptor<TFn> | void {
    const originalHandler = descriptor.value!;

    descriptor.value = function (this: any, context: HasResourceINeed, ...inputs: any) {
        context.myResource.logMetricsEtc(...inputs);

        return originalHandler.apply(this, [context, ...inputs]);
    } as TFn;
}
```

In use, with `strictFunctionTypes` enabled, this decorator causes a compile error when applied to a method that otherwise looks reasonable:

```
interface ServiceContext {
    myResource: MyResource;
    otherResource: {
        sendMessageEtc(msg: string): Promise<void>;
    };
}

class MyBusinessClass {
    // This causes a compile error, but shouldn't - the decorator will 
    // work here at runtime.
    @myDecorator
    async foo(context: ServiceContext, x: number): Promise<void> {

    }

    // This example MUST cause a compile error to prevent invalid 
    // usage - there's no resource available in the first arg for the
    // decorator to use.
    @myDecorator
    async bar(y: string): Promise<void> {

    }
}
```

The undesired compile error looks like this:

```
Argument of type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(context: ServiceContext, x: number) => Promise<void>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(tContext: HasResourceINeed, ...rest: any) => any>'.
  Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '((context: ServiceContext, x: number) => Promise<void>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((tContext: HasResourceINeed, ...rest: any) => any) | undefined'.
      Type '(context: ServiceContext, x: number) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(tContext: HasResourceINeed, ...rest: any) => any'.(2345)
```

I can't reasonably turn off `strictFunctionTypes`. Is there a way to write the decorator type to accept `foo` but reject `bar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably you want `myDecorator()`'s input to be generic in the the type `R` of the decorated method's first argument and not necessarily in the type `Fn` of the whole method.  This will allow you to accept methods whose first parameter is some subtype of `R` instead of methods which are subtypes of `Fn` (which would imply that their argument must be *supertypes* of `R` by method parameter contravariance and is not the constraint you want to apply).

Maybe like this?

```
function myDecorator<R extends HasResourceINeed>(
    _target: object,
    key: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<((tContext: R, ...rest: any) => any)>,
): TypedPropertyDescriptor<((tContext: R, ...rest: any) => any)> | void {
    const originalHandler = descriptor.value!;
    descriptor.value = function (this: any, context: R, ...inputs: any) {
        context.myResource.logMetricsEtc(...inputs);
        return originalHandler.apply(this, [context, ...inputs]);
    };
}
```

That seems to work:

```
class MyBusinessClass {

    @myDecorator // okay
    async foo(context: ServiceContext, x: number): Promise<void> {

    }

    @myDecorator // error
    async bar(y: string): Promise<void> {

    }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8BKEDOB7AVyiWQG8AoZK5AGzwHNUIwpgEcBRMBACgDoBcKPRwAuZHBDoAlOIBueYABMA3OQC+5cqEixEKABJwc2fESQBJAHIQISsskrUAtllyFiEcRlMekazXIYAhAEMGA8EGRXABEIBDwoODBEgB5MZAgAD0gQJRxkIxN3cwhrWyUAPh4nKgB9MCF6ZnE8ACMAK3iwABpa5ABrCHRxHBZQemQAH2QcdGc2vBo+6mQlXARWAAcUqHEAFXQtuwAFKDxjqDB0OJxN4B20nh4wAGFIyBzxTB7kAT4oLgwOJJDJkABeSoSKTSSp9WTIQ7HJRnC7Qa63e6PKCpZ5vD7ZYHIH5-ASAsYgmEQqGg2HTZAKZRkfoJEBjZCJYD0UBwGhGPI0aAQtYbba7PhyXkECAAQjUq3WdzFiQlUpQ4OQwVC4UiyBeAAtgGJoehfqzPkSSf9QFsCGBjbTmatVubCXxXL5Snw6IxmKx2FxeNaQLb7dJ5c6qICwEQopzuSBefylIKoHw4FstjR0Aajb8ANqunK-YOhnAAXXD-XUAS0Omg8BIAGVoHI2BB3uBCU6XG4zJ5vH2-BAI1Q8GB9dBPQOe5GcBA8kwcDg4M1AzxnDh6KNxiB6AjUc4jRBUoyqqPkDWNFoEDRjAUMAAhAg4UC4HCvO-L5n9AACsXiRJkkSZAAHpQI5AY4HQfpjHQUJNTwPAeCLIkWygNskE7C1fiycQQAIBZoAPc4j3nU9FCqH9VkCVZ-xuQCkl2MCIOgc4oFguYELaIQeBGWZd33cRD2PCjlChChqw0IA)

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to restrict the type of "this". I.e. to enforce that "MyBusinessClass" has some property that I can use in the function replacement that the decorator provides.